# How to scroll to a Label in GSAP scrollTrigger scrub Timeline

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vuetify.js, gsap

So I'm having this problem I have a `scrollTrigger` Timeline and i want a button to scroll to take me to a specific position.
I tried using seek but it didnt work even `ScrollTo` plugin lack a support for this

I have a gsap Timeline

```
const tl = gsap.timeline({
        paused: true,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: '.home',
          start: 'top top',
          end: 'bottom+=1000 top',
          pin: true,
          scrub: 0.5,
          markers: true
        },
        defaults: {
          duration: 2
        }
      })
        // Main home animation
        .to(['.left'], {
          clipPath: 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%)',
          ease: 'power1.out'
        }, 'scene')
        // Name scaling animation
        .to(['.name-title'], {
          scale: 0,
          ease: 'power1.out'
        }, 'scene')
        .from(document.getElementById('achievements'), {
          autoAlpha: 0
        }, '-=1.5')
        // Achievements reveal animation
        .from(document.getElementById('achievements').querySelectorAll('.row'), {
          motionPath: {
            path: [
              {
                x: 0,
                y: 100
              }
            ]
          },
          autoAlpha: 0,
          stagger: 0.2,
          ease: 'power3.out'
        }, '-=2')
        .addLabel('achievements')
        // Hide achievements animation
        .to(document.getElementById('achievements').querySelectorAll('.row'), {
          motionPath: {
            path: [
              {
                x: 0,
                y: -100
              }
            ]
          },
          autoAlpha: 0,
          stagger: 0.2,
          ease: 'power3.in'
        }, '+=2')
```

and i have a button in my `home` that should take me to `achievements` section but i cant find any proper solution.

Comment: How to do this was covered [on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24744-scrolltrigger-jump-to-animations/?tab=comments#comment-118565).

Comment: I couldn't find that before but thanks looks like its a similar solution to mine.

Answer (score 0):

So i deviced my own workaround solution (P.S: im using Vue)

```
scrollTo () {
      const pos = Math.ceil(document.body.scrollHeight * (this.loadTl.labels.achievements / this.loadTl.duration()))
      gsap.to(window, { duration: 2, scrollTo: pos, ease: 'linear' })
    }
```

loadTl here is a computed property for my Timeline i Found the position of `achievements` and used `ScrollToPlugin` to scroll to that pixel.

**But im looking for a better way of doing this.**